# Finder wants to make changes. Type your password to allow this System: 10.10.3

Tags: macos

Any changes in Finder gives the popup window where I am asked to type my password. I can delete files so not that earlier discussed problem. Any file taken out of finder is just copying, not remove it. It started after updating to 10.10.3 and both on iMAC and Macbook Air.

Tried everything so far....repaired my disc's permissions in reboot mode, checked terminal and compared with the empty trash problem... but nothing worked.
An solution would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you boot into safe mode (by holding the shift key on startup)?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you updating to 10.13.2 macOS High Sierra. It should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting off the recovery partition and open terminal.
Type `resetpassword` - a utility will open. At the bottom of the opened window there's a Reset button for Home Folder Permissions and ACLs.

Comment: Hi again Kevin Grabher, I just booted Repair Utilities again... to check if I had done it wrong.... After clicking the reset button for "reset home directory permissions and ACL's the button goes to OK imidiately and it's like nothing happened. I've read the process could take up to a couple of minutes - it didn't even take half a second. And restarted again - no changes. Still the same problem ;-/

Comment: Does `reset password` do something different in Recovery? Normally `reset` just resets the terminal state.